# Problem changing Database in Hibernate

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jakarta-ee, oracle10g, vpn

i'm having a problem with hibernate and don't know exactly what's going on, i have this project at work where i connect to an Oracle 10g Database using the following settings:

```
Host Name: localhost
port:1521
SID:orcl
user:anfxi
password:password
```

Now i'm at home trying to work with the same database remotely, im connected via VPN and the database ip is now `10.73.98.230` , i imported my WAR and changed the settings in my 
hibernate.cfg.xml from:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin://localhost:1521:orcl</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">anfexi</property>
<property name="connection.password">password</property>
<property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

to:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin://10.73.98.230:1521:orcl</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">anfexi</property>
<property name="connection.password">password</property>
<property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

but i keep getting this error:

```
ERROR [main] (SchemaValidator.java:135) - could not get database metadata
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
localhost:1521:orcl
```

so it seems to be still using localhost as the DB address, i cleaned my project and rebuilt, still with no luck, is there something else that i could be missing? does the hibernate configuration gets cached in some file i have to erase or something?

**EDIT**
For what it may serve, i can connect using SQL developer,the problem is just hibernate still using the old `localhost:1521:orcl` Connection descriptor.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify that the xml file you are changing in Eclipse is actually being deployed to the server.  I run into problems every once in awhile where Eclipse doesn't know it needs to redeploy certain files for my webapp.

If you are using Tomcat and deploying using the workspace metadata (the default), you can check what the actual deployed WAR files look like by looking at your filesystem under:

`WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/APPNAME/.../path/to/hibernate.cfg.xml`

If you find the config file is NOT being updated, I would recommend undeploying you app in Eclipse, deleting the entire APPNAME directory in the above path, and redeploying clean.

If none of that works, do a project-wide search for "localhost" and see if there could possible be any hardcoded connections strings anywhere.

Comment: Indeed it was deploying an old version of the hibernate.cfg.xml, and it wouldn't apply my changes no matter what, i had to undeploy, create a new project, copy my files, modify the xml and redeploy. Only then it worked. Odd behavior but is working now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of problem is usually due to the wrong configuration file being present. Maybe you have two copies of the file and you changed one but the system is using the other

Typically when building/compiling, resources get copied to a target/build folder. Check source folders and build target folders etc.

Search the file system for all files with the name hibernate.cfg.xml or with the contents localhost:1521:orcl

Check the classpath, or try explicitly putting the folder with the configuration file you want first in the classpath.

It can also be a case of some other configuration overriding your configuration, for instance a datasource filer or a persistence.xml-file. Check those if you have them as well.

How are you running your application? Through a test case, standalone console application, servlet/j2ee container?

Answer (score 0):

It is unable to understand the "orcl" SID. May be the SID is present on your "localhost" but not on the server "10.73.98.230". verify you are using the correct SID available on "10.73.98.230".

Comment: The SID is present, localhost and 10.73.98.230 are the same computer, i used the 10.73.98.230 when i connected from home, when i'm at work i can just use localhost and everything works fine...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line in your config file.

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.73.98.230:1521:orcl</property>
```

replace // with @

you can follow the link the have infomation http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/oracle/ORA12505.htm

Hope this will help